# Symfony 3 in Docker - Weird Connection Refused error

Tags: mysql, docker, doctrine-orm, symfony

Working on a Symfony 3 project.

All my CLI doctrine commandos concerning the database work, like:

`doctrine:database:create` or `doctrine:schema:update --force`

Weirdly enough, I'm trying to get some data from my repository in my controller method, but there i seem to bounce on a Connection refused error when I try to navigate to the page in question in my browser.

Below some configs:

**config.yml part**

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
          charset: utf8mb4
          collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
```

**parameters.yml**

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: db_name
    database_user: db_user
    database_password: db_pw
```

** Controller **

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
}

/**
 * @Route("/roedel", name="roedel")
 */
public function roedelAction()
{
    return $this->render('default/roedel.html.twig');
}

/**
 * @Route("/territorium", name="territorium")
 */
public function territoriumAction()
{
    return $this->render('default/territorium.html.twig');
}

/**
 * @Route("/dejacht", name="jacht")
 */
public function jachtAction()
{
    $artists = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Artist')
        ->findAll();

    return $this->render('default/jacht.html.twig', [
        'artists' => $artists
    ]);
}
}
```

Extra information:

- Using docker as this is a testcase, though I'm not sure if this should matter since CLI commandos for doctrine do work.

Comment: Are you executing the doctrine CLI commands from the docker command line (e.g. SSH), or within your operating system's command line (e.g. powershell)? If the later, since docker is a virtual machine, when you run your application within docker, it would attempt to access the mysql server from within the docker configuration at `127.0.0.1` (aka localhost) and not the hosting operating system. To simplify: please detail where mysql is installed/configured.

Comment: @fyrye I see where you're going at. i'm executing the doctrine CLI commands from my OS command line. the MySQL container is indeed running in a different container (on port 3306). This probably means I should change the credentials?

Comment: You should install/configure the mysql server in docker, and remote into it from within your OS via SSH or docker container to execute command line commands. Turning docker into your application host. This will allow you to deploy docker should the hosting OS crash/format, or to share with another developer. Otherwise you would need to configure a means for docker to communicate with your host OS's mysql configuration. See: https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/ Configuring mysql on docker will best emulate how you would deploy your app on an external server.

Comment: Oh, but I'm not using any local MySQL server software or anything, so I'm not sure if that is necessary. I'm using a docker container for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're trying to run Symfony's console command against MySQL that runs inside a docker container, then there are two possible scenarios.

**You run a symfony command from your local machine**, e.g. Mac, Windows, etc. - then the DB host has to be your docker machine IP (typically `192.168.99.100`, but depend on your configuration) and you have to have properly mapped port 3306 for mysql container - more about port mapping https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/ports.

**You run a symfony command from the "web app" container** - then the DB host is set to `mysql`, and you have to have properly configured network between the "web app" and mysql containers - more about networks https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/networks

More convenient, for me, would be the second approach, because you don't have to alter DB parameters...

Comment: The first options seems the most appropriate for me, despite not using docker-machine. Thanks, cleared up a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

you need just to add your mysql server in config.yml

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   pdo_mysql
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
    server_version: 5.7.42
```

and delete manually the cache repos /dev